# Can I create API credentials with read only access

Tags: vimeo-api

I would like to create API key, with just read only access to my vimeo account. Is there any possibility for that kind of purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating an access token, you can request a list of "scopes". These are permissions that a token has when accessing the authenticated users accounts. If you only request the public and private scopes, the token will be read only.

You can learn more about Vimeo's authentication flow (which uses the oauth2 standard) [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication).